# Rails 3 - how to search with Solr in associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, model-associations, sunspot-solr

Already whole day I am struggling with setting up the Solr for searching with associations.

I have a table **photos** and this table has a tags like **nature** or **city**. These tags are saved in the table **Tags**. In the table **photo_tags** are saved **photo_id** and **tag_id**.

When I try to help the word **nature**, I would like to get a statement of all photos with this tag, I try to do that this way (model **photo**):

```
  searchable do
    text :photo_tags do
      photo_tags.map{ |photo_tag| photo_tags.tag.name }
    end
  end
```

But I don't get the photos with the tag...

**EDIT** - my associations:

```
photo.rb
  has_many :photo_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :photo_tags

photo_tag.rb
  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to :tag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use `photo_tags` and not `photo_tag`in the map?

Maybe this should resolve the issue:

```
searchable do
  text :photo_tags do
    photo_tags.map{ |photo_tag| photo_tag.name }
  end
end
```

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work me, I added to my original question associations

Comment: The name of the association you want to use seems to be `tags` and not `photo_tags`so you can try `tags.map{...}` instead of `photo_tags.map{...}`

Comment: Pretty sure he's right, use `tags.map(&:name)` and you should be fine.